# MYSQLI query doesn't insert info in database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form and code to upload the info and an image. Everything is working, the image is getting resized and placed in the correct folder. After that I have code to insert the info into the database.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `artigos` VALUES ('','$titulo','$nome','$corpo','$categoria','','')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

//se a query existe entao a pagina é redireccionada

if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) != 0)
{
    $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Artigo inserido com sucesso!</span>';
    echo $sucesso;
}
```

I get the message "Artigo inserido com sucesso" but the info doesn't appear in the database. MY $con is the mysqli connect. All the variables exist, I get no error when I press the button, but the info doesn't go to the database. My 'artigos' table contains these fields:

id_artigo, titulo, img, corpo, id_categoria, id_user, date(timestamp).

What is wrong?

Comment: can you give me a image of structure of the table from phpmyadmin

Comment: i edited the post try the code now @user3375665

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
 $query = "$query = "INSERT INTO artigos(titulo, img, corpo, id_categoria,id_user) VALUES ('{$titulo}','{$nome}','{$corpo}',{'$categoria'}, 4";";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

//se a query existe entao a pagina é redireccionada

if (mysqli_affected_rows($con)!=0)

{

$sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Artigo inserido com sucesso!</span>';

echo $sucesso;

}

?>
```

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO `artigos` (titulo, img, corpo, id_categoria) VALUES ({$titulo}','{$nome},'{$corpo}','{$categoria}')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);.
it still didnt worked

Comment: it didnt worked. Still no data on the database, but i still get the $sucesso echo

Comment: ok i will edit the answer to get it to work

Comment: Still not working ..

Comment: i know i am working on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96508/discussion-between-lyndact-and-user3375665).